# undefined is not a function(evaluating'_this.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get access to 'Home' from Form.js. But my code shows that error. How can I fix it?

I tried in arrowF, routes and nothing works. Same error...

> This is my Form.js where I call onPress=() I tried function, navigation and nothing works. I try add const { navigation } = this.props; and nothing works. Same error.

```
<View style={styles.viewChild}>
  <TouchableHighlight
     onPress={this._Home} title="Home"
     style={styles.button} >
   <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 16}}>Acessar</Text>
 </TouchableHighlight>
```

> This is my Login.js. Where I call  Component

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Container, Top, Logo, Title, Content
} from './styles';

import Form from '~/components/Form/form';
import logo from '~/assets/logo.png';
import { MaterialTopTabBar, navigation } from 'react-navigation';

export default function Login(){
  return (
    <Container>
      <Top>
        <Logo source={logo} />
        <Title
          style={MaterialTopTabBar.display1}
        >Welcome</Title>
      </Top>
      <Content>
        <Form />
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

> This is my Route.js I tried changes between Stack, BottomNav, and nothing works. The Route from Form.js to 'Home' failed. I can post my GitHub.

```js
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';

import Form from '~/components/Form/form';
import Home from '~/pages/Home/home';
import Main from '~/pages/Main';

const Routes = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator({
    Main: {screen: Main},
    Form: {screen: Form},
    Home: {screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home',
      headerBackTitle: null,
    }}
   }),
);

export default Routes;
```

Comment: What is that: `onPress={this._Home} title="Home"`?

Comment: it was a function. to call 'Home'. I tried as props and it doesnt work.

Comment: Is it where you call `this.props.navigate`? Please post the content so we can take a look.

Comment: Can you show the code of the _Home function?

Answer (score 0):

The function is used as follows:

```js
func1(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Form");
}
...
 <TouchableHighlight
     onPress={this.func1.bind(this)} title="Home"

or

 <TouchableHighlight
     onPress={() => this.func1()} title="Home"
```

use Arrow function

```js
const func1 = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Form");
}
...
 <TouchableHighlight
     onPress={this.func1} title="Home"
```